# SharePoint webparts in a html file

Tags: web-part, html

Dear SharePoint Masters,

Since my boss hates SharePoint's interface but has no other choices. He asked me to do a HTML/CSS page and integrate some webparts such like search bar into it. Is it possible to use a fully customized website and filled with SharePoint functionalities?

Comment: Best option for you is to customize (Brand) your SharePoint Master page. you can use the SharePoint with having your custom UI in it.

Comment: SharePoint can be branded any way you want with HTML/CSS, search for branding and Masterpages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can entirely change the look of a SharePoint site as well. You need not go for another HTML page to add stuff. It is easier to brand your SharePoint site itself. You will need to customize the master page. Have a look at [this article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-a-master-page-to-brand-your-site-0a57b837-4c97-4af9-a088-fedf3dfd1dd5)

If you are using SharePoint 2013. It is easier to customize master pages.

Here are few links for your reference.

- [msdn article 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506214.aspx)
- [msdn article 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj862339.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer, I'm going to learn these courses.